# I am trying to obtain a desired colored rounded button. I got the desired rounded bottom but it doesn't change its color after making clicks

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am beginner in kivy. Here I am trying to use a button in custom color and make it rounded. I obtained the desired button which is indeed rounded. But The obtained button doesn't change it's color when clicking. I want to make it change the color when clicking like in case of default rectangular button. But i don't have any idea how to do it. I tried different ways like using 'button_down' property of documentation and using on_press event and all but I couldnot solve the problem. Please Help me guide how to do so. thanks in advance

**my.kv file**

```py
RoundedButton:
    text: "Lets Go"
    text_color_normal: (0,0,0,1)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
    size_hint:(0.2,0.2)
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color:  (0, 0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (3/255, 252/255, 65/255,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [28]
```

**MainWindow.py program**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv= Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class Mainpage(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Mainpage()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that by defining the colors that you want for when the `RoundedButton` is up and another when it is down. Here is a portion of a modified version of your `kv` that does that:

```
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color:  (0, 0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    up_color: (3/255, 252/255, 65/255,1)
    down_color: (1,0,0,1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.up_color if self.state == 'normal' else self.down_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [28]
```

Comment: First ,Thanks for your help, It really meant a lot, Now i have the button changing color  when clicked but it is no longer rounded. It became rectangular. I tried fixing it by playing around with background_color values, and I also read about up_color and down_color from  documentation. I tried to use the code given by you. It would be great if you suggest me now what is happening with it?? I am not able to figure out why it is showing rectangular button.

Comment: The code in my answer produces a rounded rectangle button. Perhaps there is something else going in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I found out the issue and it was with my wrong class declaration. Finally, I am able to obtain the desired functionality of my button.

Comment: That is an excellent solution